# From a Activity to another Activity that opens a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I have a Activity that is my menu from where I try to open a another activity that opens my `SurfaceView`.

My problem is that with a Button and an `onClickListener` I can't start my game. And my other problem is by going back from the `SurfaceView` to the menu with an `Context` call what also crashes the game.

**This is my class that opens the `SurfaceView`**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView= new GLSurfaceView(this);
    GLSurfaceView.context=this;
    setContentView(GLSurfaceView);
}
```

**The Menu class where I try to open the other activity**

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menue);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent Intent = new Intent(Menue.this ,MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(Intent);}
});
```

**My SurfaceView**

```
public GLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    renderer = new Renderer();
    setRenderer(renderer);

    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @Mauker with the crash i mean on the app when i run the game and i get to the point of gameover it will just stop. On android studio isnt anyything written as i can see

Comment: The app is closing?

Comment: @Mauker yes insted of going to the menu class